# Why is my scroll to top always animated? And how can I instantly travel to top?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this heavily animated website made and every time I apply "Back to top" code on my button, it always animates scrolling through the entire page until it reaches the top.

I want it to instantly take them to the top without any fancy scroll up effects which is what I am getting..

I have tried multiple scripts and they all get an animation for some reason (even if I search for script code that is supposedly not animated).

this is the current script I am using: (I have tried multiple but they all resulted in the same animated scroll up effect)

```
<!-- Back to top -->
    <script>
        var btn = $('#BackTop');
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300) {
                btn.addClass('show');
            } else {
                btn.removeClass('show');
            }
        });

        btn.on('click', function(e) {
            // e.preventDefault();
            window.scrollTo({
                top: 0,
            })
        });
    </script>
```

These are the other scripts included in the page, could have any of these been effecting my scroll to top code perhaps?

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my-assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my-assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/lib/gsap3/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./my-assets/js/scroll.js"></script>

    <!-- .cd-vertical-nav -->
    <script src="./my-assets/js/velocity.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./my-assets/js/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./my-assets/js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- fade effect js -->
    <script src="./my-assets/js/aos/aos.js"></script>
```

Would appreciate any tips with what exactly am I doing wrong, because I really want it to be instant to top and not animated because the page I am working on is huge in a sense where I dont want the costumer to see the entire page scroll back up..

Comment: i think this the answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143706/jquery-scrolltop-without-animation#answer-10182437

Comment: @RobinHood I have tried that solution before, but I still get an animation for some reason..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of css properties on the document.

You can either specify the behaviour for the particular operation

```
window.scrollTo({ top:0, left:0, behavior: "instant"}); // using built in
$(window).scrollTo(0, {duration:0}); // using jquery
```

Other than that you could try changing the css properties of the document

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the built in example worked for me! for some reason the jquery method kept adding a scroll effect and wasnt just doing it instantly.

Answer (score 0):

For that you don't even need JS. You can set empty or hidden div in top of you page and give it some **id**. And make your `btn` be `a` tag that links to it

```
<a href="#id">
```

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_id_bookmark) is the example

**Alternatives**

If you want to use **JS** you can

```
document.getElementById("body").scrollIntoView()
```

Or **JQuery**

```
$(window).scrollTo(0, {duration:0})
```

Comment: I have tried this method before, but for some reason every time I use jquery it added an animation, but I tried a built in method suggested by another answer and it fixed my porblem!